# Solve Multivariate Integral with Matrix Exponential

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, matrix-calculus

My calculus skills are a bit rusty. Can somebody help me to solve the following integral?

$$\int_{t_0}^t f(s)f(s)^\top ds$$

with $$f(s)=e^{A(t-s)}Q$$

where $A$ is an invertible matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\int_{t_0}^t f(s)f(s)^Tds=e^{tA}.\int_{t_0}^te^{-sA}QQ^Te^{-sA^T}ds .e^{tA^T}$.

If $e^{-sA}Q$ and $A$ are normal and if $A+A^T$ is invertible, then $\int_{t_0}^te^{-sA}QQ^Te^{-sA^T}ds=Q^T\int_{t_0}^te^{-s(A+A^T)}dsQ=Q^T(A+A^T)^{-1}(e^{-t_0(A+A^T)}-e^{-t(A+A^T)})Q$